# Deeplink isn't correctly redirect if the app is already opened

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation, android-deep-link

I'm using Jetpack Navigation for deeplinks. I've added `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to my Activity.
Deeplink is redirected correctly if the app wasn't opened before. However, if the app exists in memory, the app is coming to the foreground but deeplink isn't opened correctly.

My device is Pixel 2 with Android 10.
I see that `onCreate` is called only the first time I'm opening app. However, `onNewIntent` is called every time I'm clicking deeplink.

Is it a bug in Jetpack Navigation or I forgot about something when setting it up?

Comment: It seems normal. When activity already created just its onNewIntent method called for this process. You should put your logic inside the onNewIntent method.

Comment: This is the intended behavior of single task launch mode.

Comment: But why Jetpack Navigation is not handling it by default?

Answer (score 10):

As per the [`handleDeepLink()` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#handleDeepLink(android.content.Intent)):

> This is called automatically for you the first time you set the graph if you've passed in an `Activity` as the context when constructing this NavController, **but should be manually called if your Activity receives new Intents in `Activity.onNewIntent(Intent)`**.

`NavController` doesn't override methods in your activity, so you'd need to call this manually if you insist on using `android:launchMode="singleTask"`.

As per the [Single Activity talk](https://youtu.be/2k8x8V77CrU?t=1683), you shouldn't use any `launchMode` flags at all - the default is actually what you want 99.9% of the time.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I'm using Branch SDK and `singleTask` is required by this 3rd party. My pattern to handle deeplinks I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61481816/jetpack-navigation-handling-deeplinks-manually-in-onnewintent it's not the most beautiful, but seems to work. Cheers