# Jetpack Navigation handling deeplinks manually in onNewIntent

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation, android-deep-link

I'm using Jetpack Navigation.
I need to handle deeplinks manually because:

1) Implicit deeplinks are not working properly with `android:launchMode="singleTask"` [Deeplink isn't correctly redirect if the app is already opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61480730/deeplink-isnt-correctly-redirect-if-the-app-is-already-opened)

2) I'm passing in my bundles not only simple types but also Parcelables, so I won't have the possibility to pass arguments

I've done proof of concept that is using explicit deeplinkins in `onNewintent` of my Activity

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    val data: Uri? = intent?.data

    if(data?.lastPathSegment == "discover") {
        val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(this)
            .setGraph(R.navigation.nav_main)
            .setDestination(R.id.discover_dest)
            .createPendingIntent()

        pendingIntent.send()
    }
}
```

It works on my phone, but to be honest, it smells. Is it an intended way to use Jetpack Navigation explicit deeplinks?
Can I handle manually Jetpack Navigation deeplinks in the nicer way?

Comment: Have you defined better way?

Comment: Nope, it stayed that way.